# OCTOBERCMS Form and Model

Tags: php, laravel, forms, model, octobercms

I'm a newbie in OctoberCms and i don't have much knowledge in Laravel also. While self studying I face a request like this it's a Select if record exist query I need to read the database and look for the match and I'm really confuse.

This is my form in form.htm where I design my Form.

```
use Drufal\DynamicContentManager\Models\MembersVerification;
==
   <form data-request="onSend" accept-charset="UTF8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>First Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Middle Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="middle_name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Last Name:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

and this my model

```
<?php namespace Drufal\DynamicContentManager\Models;

use Model;
use Input;

/**
 * Model
 */
class MembersVerification extends Model
{
use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Validation;

/*
 * Disable timestamps by default.
 * Remove this line if timestamps are defined in the database table.
 */
public $timestamps = false;

/**
 * @var array Validation rules
 */
public $rules = [
];

/**
 * @var string The database table used by the model.
 */
public $table = 'drufal_dynamiccontentmanager_members';

   public function onSend(){
        $fn = Input::get('first_name');
        $mn = Input::get('middle_name');
        $ln = Input::get('last_name');
      $membertbl=$table::where('first_name', '=', $fn)->first();
        if ($membertbl === null) {
           echo"
                <script>
                alert('Successfully');
                </script>

                ";
        }else{
            echo"NO RESULT";
            }     
    }
}
```

Help the newbie please.

Comment: hmm `onSend` you need to add that inside your page's code section, and for message you can use https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/extras#ajax-flash before using it please read docu. you need to read docu for better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the DB:: in your database request:

```
$users = Db::table('users')->where('votes', 100)->first();
```

Maybe this documentation will help you:

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/query#where-clauses